# constexpr string literals in anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have the following example code which uses a string literal as a template parameter, such that the base class template can access the string.

The code compiles, but I get a warning which I do not fully understand:

> warning: ‘ns::bar::type’ has a base ‘ns::base<((const char*)(&
>   ns::bar::name))>’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace [enabled by
>   default]

Working example code below:

```
// "test.h"
#pragma once

namespace ns 
{
    template <char const* str>
    struct base
    {
        const char *name() const { return str; }
    };

    namespace bar 
    {
        static constexpr char name[] = "bar";
        struct type : base<name> {};                // <-- this line here
    }
}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    ns::bar::type f;
    std::cout << f.name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So my questions are:

1. What does this warning mean?
2. Is it safe to pass a string literal as a template parameter in the way that I am doing here?

(Note this is with gcc 4.7.2)

Comment: #2 is easy to answer: Yes it's safe, as long as you always use `ns::bar::name` as the template parameter; another, separate string with the contents "bar" may not be at the same location in memory (and certainly won't be with optimizations off, e.g. during a debug build), which would lead to a separate `base<>` instantiation (albeit one which behaves the same way).

Comment: So I could potentially use a `#pragma` to disable this warning around this particular instantiation and still feel warm and happy? (if one such pragma actually exists - can't seem to find it with a cursory google)

Comment: No idea ;-) The warning is new to me too. I only addressed the second half of your question. What compiler are you using? (Ah never mind, I see it's gcc 4.7.2). I can't reproduce the warning with gcc 4.7.2. And I don't see the *anonymous* namespace you mentioned?

Comment: Hmmm - considering that a type with internal linkage defined in a header will be a different type in every file that includes the header, would doing this actually be in error? Perhaps #2 is not safe after all?

Comment: @Cameron - are you putting splitting the code out into 2 separate files? The first half has to be in a header. If you compile it all in 1 file then you don't get the warning - I'm guessing because there is now no internal-linkage issue?

Comment: @lori: Oops, there's my mistake! I put it all in one file. Yes, you are right -- #2 shouldn't be safe unless `name` exists (in terms of allocated memory) only in one translation unit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is do with the fact that `static constexpr char name[] = "bar";` has internal linkage.

**Any type with internal linkage defined in a header will be a different type in every file that includes the header.**

This is seldom the intention - hence the warning.

The reason there is no warning for when this is done in a source file is because that type can't ever be referred to by more than one file - hence it will always be that one type.

Comment: +1, though to nitpick the *type* is the same, just not the instance in memory.

Comment: @Cameron untrue. `base<name>` is a different type in different "files".

Comment: @Johannes: I was referring to `name[]`, but you're certainly right about `base<name>` being a different type everywhere. Yay templates! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The warning is because `name` will have a different address in each source file that `test.h` is included into.  Because it has internal linkage (`static`) each translation unit will get its own copy; they will not be unified by the linker.  This means that your code is equivalent to:

```
template<int> struct base { ... };
static constexpr int val = some_value_different_in_every_source_file;
struct type: base<val> {};
```

Your code is legal *as presented*, but if you include `test.h` in another source file then it will violate the one-definition rule:

> #### 3.2 One deﬁnition rule [basic.def.odr]
>
> [...]
> 6 - There can be more than one definition of a class type [...] provided [...]: [...]
>
> - in each deﬁnition of `D`, corresponding names [...] can refer to a const object
>   with internal or no linkage [only] if [...] the value (but not the address) of the object is used [...]

You're using the *address* of an object with internal linkage in the definition of a class type, so using it in more than one translation unit is undefined behaviour.

Comment: is there any way to force `name` to have **external linkage** *and* use it in the manner I described above? ie; `extern` or some such?

Comment: @lori you can declare it `const char name[];` and define it in a single source file e.g. `main.cpp`.

Comment: do you mean `extern const char name[];`?