# CPP warning : "‘B’ has a base ‘A<(& str)>’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace" while using a template string

Tags: c++, templates, warnings

Here is the simplest code I can give:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "test.h"

int main() { return 0; }
```

```cpp
// test.h
#pragma once
#include <cstring>

const char str[] = "ABCD";

template <
    const char* str,
    std::size_t N
>
class A {};

class B : public A<str, strlen(str)> {};
```

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include "test.h"
```

When I compile, I get twice the following warning:

```
test.h:13:7: warning: ‘B’ has a base ‘A<(& str), 4>’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace [-Wsubobject-linkage]
   13 | class B : public A<str, strlen(str)> {};
      |       ^
```

The reason why I get it twice is because `test.h` is included twice, once in `main.cpp` and once in `test.cpp`.

A similar question has already been answering in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951200/constexpr-string-literals-in-anonymous-namespace), but there was only a `const char*` and not a `std::size_t` too.

The answer of the above linked post was to use the `extern` keyword before `const char str[]` and define `str` in the `test.cpp`. But with `std::size_t` the compilation with the corrected code gives the following error:

```
test.h:13:31: error: ‘strlen(((const char*)(& str)))’ is not a constant expression
   13 | class B : public A<str, strlen(str)> {};
      |                         ~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Of course my code is more complicated than that and the main problem is that my object only need a `const char*`, the `strlen(str)` is done by another templated class far behind.

How can I do things to not have warnings or errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) can't be used in a constexpr context. You can use [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). Also you need to make `str` array `inline` for letting the compiler know `str` array size.

```
inline const char str[] = "ABCD";

lass B : public A<str, std::size(str) - 1> {};
```

Comment: with this I get the following error : `error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
  246 |     -> decltype(__cont.size())`, are you sure it works with `const char*`?

Comment: @Ephesiel: Do you have `extern const char str[5];`?

Comment: Got it, the answer is updated.

Comment: Okay, it works if I specify the length of the string in the brackets. `extern const char str[5]`. I also find in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801432/why-do-i-get-the-child-has-a-base-whose-type-uses-the-anonymous-namespace-warn) that the `inline` keyword worked in my case. Thanks.

Comment: *"GCC (and other compilers) treat `strlen` as a 'constexpr' function as an extension to the language."* That might make OP code working.